Openvpn client into kubernenetes pods
I’m relatively new to networking and Kubernetes, but I need to perform a load test on an OpenVPN server.
Here’s what I’ve done so far:
I created a Docker image that includes an OpenVPN client.
I set up a Kubernetes cluster using Minikube to run a Job that executes Pods containing my Docker image with OpenVPN.
I’m using Calico as the CNI in IPinIP mode.
I configured a Service with NodePort.
When I run my Pods, I can successfully establish a VPN tunnel. I can confirm this because:
The tun interface is mounted in each of my Pods.
The server logs and status file show that the tunnels are open.
However, I’m facing an issue: the tun0 interface in my Pods is effectively useless. From what I understand, it is not properly routed outside of my Node. I’m stuck and can’t figure out how to make the tun0 interface in my Pods connect externally through Calico.
Below there are some command that I used to understand my issue into my pod.
Ping using tun0 iface
module-update-job-0:/home/root# ping 8.8.8.8 -I tun0
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8): 56 data bytes
^C
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100% packet loss

Ping using eth0 iface
module-update-job-0:/home/root# ping 8.8.8.8 -I eth0
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: seq=0 ttl=113 time=10.461 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: seq=1 ttl=113 time=10.380 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: seq=2 ttl=113 time=13.003 ms
^C
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 10.380/11.281/13.003 ms

Interfaces mounted into my pod
module-update-job-0:/home/root# ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever    inet6 ::1/128 scope host proto kernel_lo        valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: tunl0@NONE: <NOARP> mtu 1480 qdisc tbf state DOWN group default qlen 1000    link/ipip 0.0.0.0 brd 0.0.0.0
4: eth0@if42: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc tbf state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 9e:39:6c:ed:65:38 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
    inet 192.168.100.81/32 scope global eth0       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::9c39:6cff:feed:6538/64 scope link proto kernel_ll 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: tun0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1380 qdisc tbf state UNKNOWN group default qlen 500
    link/none 
    inet 192.168.X.X peer 192.168.X.X/32 scope global tun0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::bcc5:57a:f07e:b61a/64 scope link stable-privacy proto kernel_ll 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

Routes into my pods after vpn client execution
module-update-job-0:/home/root# routes
bash: routes: command not found
module-update-job-0:/home/root# route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         192.168.16.5    128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun0
default         169.254.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
128.0.0.0       192.168.16.5    128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun0
169.254.1.1     *               255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 eth0
172.17.16.79    169.254.1.1     255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 eth0
192.168.16.0    192.168.16.5    255.255.240.0   UG    0      0        0 tun0
192.168.16.5    *               255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun0

Traceroute through eth0
traceroute to 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8), 30 hops max, 46 byte packets
 1  192.168.49.2 (192.168.49.2)  0.006 ms  0.040 ms  0.034 ms
 2  192.168.49.1 (192.168.49.1)  0.008 ms  0.010 ms  0.007 ms
 3  192.168.200.254 (192.168.200.254)  0.528 ms  0.571 ms  0.436 ms
 4  X.X.X.X (X.X.X.X)  1.083 ms  1.115 ms  1.052 ms
 5  X.X.X.X (X.X.X.X)  2.156 ms  2.117 ms  2.109 ms
 6  X.X.X.X (X.X.X.X)  12.101 ms  11.581 ms  13.382 ms
 7  X.X.X.X (X.X.X.X)  10.640 ms  12.218 ms  12.060 ms
 8  X.X.X.X (X.X.X.X)  11.569 ms  14.146 ms  12.000 ms
 9  X.X.X.X (X.X.X.X)  10.433 ms  10.512 ms  10.330 ms
10  X.X.X.X (X.X.X.X)  10.355 ms  94.228.177.30 (94.228.177.30)  10.937 ms  11.495 ms
11  *  *  *
12  8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8)  10.430 ms  10.304 ms  142.250.234.41 (142.250.234.41)  10.975 ms

Traceroute through tun0
module-update-job-0:/home/root# traceroute 8.8.8.8 -i tun0
traceroute to 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8), 30 hops max, 46 byte packets
 1  192.168.16.1 (192.168.16.1)  11.639 ms  11.637 ms  11.398 ms
 2  *  *  *
 3  *  *  *

Below are my kubernetes job definition,
Job configuration
The '%' characters are completed by sed in a Bash script.
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: module-update-job
spec:
  completions: %COMPLETION%
  parallelism: %PARALLELISM%
  completionMode: Indexed
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: module-update-pod
      annotations:
        #k8s.v1.cni.cncf.io/networks: "direct-host-network"
        #cni.projectcalico.org/ipv4pools: "[\"192.168.100.0/24\"]"
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: module-update-conn
        image: module-update:latest
        imagePullPolicy: Never
        securityContext:
          privileged: true
          capabilities:
            add:
              - NET_ADMIN
              - NET_RAW
        tty: dev
        stdin: true
        env:
        - name: POD_ID
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.name  # Unique pod name as BOARD_ID
        - name: JOB_COMPLETION_INDEX
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.annotations['batch.kubernetes.io/job-completion-index']
        - name: GATEWAY_IP
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: status.podIP
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5686
          protocol: UDP
        - containerPort: 21
          protocol: TCP  # FTP Control Channel
        volumeMounts:
        # Individual file mappings
        - name: client-crt
          mountPath: /media/edenv/openvpn/client.crt
        - name: client-key
          mountPath: /media/edenv/openvpn/client.key
        - name: ca-crt
          mountPath: /media/edenv/openvpn/ca.crt
        - name: conf
          mountPath: /etc/openvpn/client.conf
        - name: script-down
          mountPath: /etc/openvpn/script_down.sh
        - name: scripts
          mountPath: /home/root/.
        - name: tun-device
          mountPath: /dev/net/tun
        command: [./integration_test.sh, "k8s", "%VPN_IP%", "%VPN_PORT%"]
      restartPolicy: Never
      volumes:
      # Define host paths
      - name: client-crt
        hostPath:
          path: %HOME%/ed-load-testing-tools/k8s-integration-test/secret/client.crt
          type: File
      - name: client-key
        hostPath:
          path: %HOME%/ed-load-testing-tools/k8s-integration-test/secret/client.key
          type: File
      - name: ca-crt
        hostPath:
          path: %HOME%/ed-load-testing-tools/k8s-integration-test/secret/ca.crt
          type: File
      - name: conf
        hostPath:
          path: %HOME%/ed-load-testing-tools/k8s-integration-test/openvpn/client.conf
          type: File
      - name: script-down
        hostPath:
          path: %HOME%/ed-load-testing-tools/k8s-integration-test/openvpn/script_down.sh
          type: File
      - name: scripts
        hostPath:
          path: %HOME%/ed-load-testing-tools/k8s-integration-test/scripts
          type: Directory
      - name: tun-device
        hostPath:
          path: /dev/net/tun
          type: CharDevice

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: module-update-service
  namespace: default
spec:
  selector:
    app: module-update-pod
  ports:
  - protocol: UDP
    name: udp
    port: 5686      # Exposed Service port
    targetPort: 5686 # Container port mapped
  - protocol: TCP
    name: ftp-crtl
    port: 21         # FTP control channel
    targetPort: 21
  - protocol: TCP
    name: ftp-data
    port: 5000 # FTP passive mode data ports
    targetPort: 5000
  type: NodePort

---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: allow-ingress-egress
  namespace: default
spec:
  podSelector: {}
  policyTypes:
  - Ingress
  - Egress
  ingress:
  - {}
  egress:
  - {}

